# CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' problem when deployed NextJS app on Nginx server tries GET request to local Express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, next.js

When I was on my local machine it works; but when uploaded to my droplet with nginx/1.18.0 and certbot giving my domain https, I get an error trying using a GET request (on my NextJS app - localhost:3000) to my express route (npm-script: `"node_1": "nodemon --watch dev -e js dev/networkNode.js 3001 http://localhost:3001"`).

The error is `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/blockchain' from origin 'https://chalkcoin.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.`
[image]

I tried changing the corsOptions to `origin: "https://chalkcoin.io"` and `origin: "*"` for `app.use(cors(corsOptions))`. I have tried leaving http: and https: off the `//localhost:3001/blockchain` in Blockchain.Context.js axios request.

I have also tried putting `<meta httpEquiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"></meta>` in the `<Head>` component of `_app,js`

Which brings me here, what's the best approach on being able to run my npm command for node_1 with pm2 in the background while my Nextjs app runs on localhost:3000.

**Express backend (localhost:3001):**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const Blockchain = require("./blockchain");
const uuid = require("uuid/v1");
const port = process.argv[2];
const rp = require("request-promise");

const nodeAddress = uuid().split("-").join("");
var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // For legacy browser support
};

const app = express();
const coin = new Blockchain();

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/blockchain", function (req, res) {
    res.json(coin);
});


app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
});
```

**Blockchain.Context.js:**

```
import { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import blockchainReducer from "../reducers/Blockchain.Reducer";

Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function () {
    var mm = this.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth() is zero-based
    var dd = this.getDate();
    return [this.getFullYear(), (mm > 9 ? "" : "0") + mm, (dd > 9 ? "" : "0") + dd].join("");
};

export const BlockchainContext = createContext();
export const BlockchainDispatch = createContext();
export function BlockchainProvider(props) {
    const [blockchain, dispatch] = useReducer(blockchainReducer, {
        chain: [],
        pendingTransactions: [],
        currentNodeUrl: "",
        networkNodes: [],
        initialized: false,
        selectedBlock: [],
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getBlockchainData() {
            try {
                const getNode1 = `http://localhost:3001/blockchain`;
                const res = await axios.get(getNode1);

                dispatch({type: "INIT", data: res.data});
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
        getBlockchainData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <BlockchainContext.Provider value={blockchain}>
            <BlockchainDispatch.Provider value={dispatch}>{props.children}</BlockchainDispatch.Provider>
        </BlockchainContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/config**

```
server {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name chalkcoin.io www.chalkcoin.io;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /node1 {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/chalkcoin.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/chalkcoin.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
    if ($host = www.chalkcoin.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = chalkcoin.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name chalkcoin.io www.chalkcoin.io;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem for Firefox and Chrome but Safari is still giving me trouble. So the Firefox and Chrome error was the CORS header wasn't equal to the value supplied. How I solved this was by changing the string interpolation in the axios.get a request to a regular string. And added the CORS options in the express app file.

```
const getNode1 = "http://localhost:3001/blockchain";
const res = await axios.get(getNode1);
```

```
const corsOptions = {
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // For legacy browser support
    credentials: true, // This is important.
    origin: "https://chalkcoin.io",
};

const app = express();

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

I believe the string interpolation syntax causes this error because CORS can't accept wildcards.

But I still don't know why Safari is giving this error. Is it because my domain is HTTPS and I'm making a request to an HTTP?
[image]